# Reusing a component having a dropdown list twice in a different component template in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have a common component consisting of a Dropdown list. Now I want to use this common component in a template of different component twice but  user can select different value for both places.
Could anyone please suggest How to do this.
**Currently I am getting same value for both places by using @Input.**

Template of component where I need to use the dropdown common component twice:

```
<dropdown-component [dropDownList]="dropdownValues" (select)="action($event.value)" ></dropdown-component>
  <dropdown-component [dropDownList]="dropdownValues" (select)="action1($event.value)" ></dropdown-component>
```

Dropdown component ts:

```
  @Input() dropDownList: string[] = [];
    @Output() select: EventEmitter<any>;
    constructor()
     { 
    this.select = new EventEmitter();
  }
  
    selectItem(value) {
    this.select.emit(value);
  }
```

Dropdown template:

```
<select >

  <option *ngFor="let label of dropDownList" [value]="label" (click)="selectItem(label)"> {{ label }} </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Welcome :-). This question can have many answers. Could you post some code please? Ideally the dropdown component.ts and the template in which you use that component

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have updated the code in the question. Please check @jnelson